How to resolve "ITMS-90129: The bundle uses a bundle name or display name that is already taken" for new builds of the same app
This error is reaction on new build created and uploaded to AppStore with new project but same bundleId/displayName/signingInfo.
Here is the scenario with symbolic values to explain it better:
Build #1 (Version 1.0)

project: P1
Bundle id: com.some.app
Display name: My App
Signing info: TeamX, CertificateX (automatic signing)

I had to move the app to new project with completely new targets/configs/sources but same app metadata.
Build #2 (Version 1.0)

project: P2 (new)
Bundle id: com.some.app
Display name: My App
Signing info: TeamX, CertificateX (automatic signing)

So you can see that all is changed but the important app metadata (BundleId, DisplayName, Signing info) remained the same.
Yet the upload of build 2 results with: ITMS-90129: The bundle uses a bundle name or display name that is already taken
Note that the Build #2 showed in "AppStoreConnect / TestFlight / iOS Builds / Version 1.0" for a few seconds as "Processing" but than disapeared with the error. Thus Apple tries to add the new build #2 it to proper application version but than for some reason it thinks that Build #1 and #2 comes from different applications.
Any thoughts why?

It was caused by different PRODUCT_NAME. If this differs then ITC thinks it's a different application regardless your equal bundleId and signing data.
